# MyBatis configuration

Tags: java, mybatis

I want to use interface instead of mapper XML file in MyBatis. In the MyBatis configuration file I define mapper
`<mapper class="aa.B" />` where B contains methods annotated with MyBatis annotations. When I try to create a mapper instance `session.getMapper(B.class);` I get an error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "class" must be declared for element type "mapper".

How can I use interfaces to map SQL statements here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add Mapper Interface via the sqlconfig xml file, you've to use the Java API

```
Configuration.addMapper(B.class)
```

The  node in sqlconfig xml is for definding sqlmap XMLs, not Mapper Interfaces.
Or you could use mybatis-spring, which has support to auto add all the mappers in a said package, to the sqlsessionfactory's configuration.

Comment: Then, what's the purpose of '<mapper class="org.mybatis.builder.AuthorMapper"/>' in http://www.mybatis.org/core/configuration.html#mappers?

Comment: @Johnny, May be something they added in a later release. My answer was on Apr 3rd, while the page you link is last updated on April 19th.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is occurred by absence of the attribute 'class' in 'mapper' element in DTD.

For example, in MyBatis 3.0.1, 'mapper' doesn't have the 'class' attribute in DTD like this:

```
<!ATTLIST mapper
resource CDATA #IMPLIED
url CDATA #IMPLIED
>
```

You need to upgrade your MyBatis library to latest one like 3.1.1.

In the version, the attribute definition of 'mapper' is as follows:

```
<!ATTLIST mapper
resource CDATA #IMPLIED
url CDATA #IMPLIED
class CDATA #IMPLIED
>
```

You can find your DTD file in the following path in your MyBatis library:

> org/apache/ibatis/builder/xml/mybatis-3-config.dtd